# Rails 5 Rspec receive with ActionController::Params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5

I have just upgraded to Rails 5. In my specs I have the following

`expect(model).to receive(:update).with(foo: 'bar')`

But, since `params` no longer extends `Hash` but is now `ActionController::Parameters` the specs are failing because `with()` is expecting a hash but it is actually `ActionController::Parameters`

Is there a better way of doing the same thing in Rspec such as a different method `with_hash`?

I can get around the issue using

`expect(model).to receive(:update).with(hash_including(foo: 'bar'))`

But that is just checking if the params includes that hash, not checking for an exact match.

Answer (score 15):

You could do:

```
params = ActionController::Parameters.new(foo: 'bar')
expect(model).to receive(:update).with(params)
```

However it still smells - you should be testing the behaviour of the application - not how it does its job.

```
expect {
  patch model_path(model), params: { foo: 'bar' }
  model.reload
}.to change(model, :foo).to('bar')
```

This is how I would test the integration of a controller:

```
require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.describe "Things", type: :request do
  describe "PATCH /things/:id" do

    let!(:thing) { create(:thing) }
    let(:action) do
      patch things_path(thing), params: { thing: attributes }
    end

    context "with invalid params" do
      let(:attributes) { { name: '' } }
      it "does not alter the thing" do
         expect do 
           action 
           thing.reload
         end.to_not change(thing, :name)
         expect(response).to have_status :bad_entity
      end
    end

    context "with valid params" do
      let(:attributes) { { name: 'Foo' } }
       it "updates the thing" do
         expect do 
           action 
           thing.reload
         end.to change(thing, :name).to('Foo')
         expect(response).to be_successful
      end
    end
  end
end
```

#### Is touching the database in a spec inheritenly bad?

No. When you are testing something like a controller the most accurate way to test it is by driving the full stack. If we in this case had stubbed out `@thing.update` we could have missed for example that the database driver threw an error because we where using the wrong SQL syntax.

If you are for example testing scopes on a model then a spec that stubs out the DB will give you little to no value.

Stubbing may give you a fast test suite that is extremely brittle due to tight coupling and that lets plenty of bugs slip through the cracks.

Comment: I've always thought that hitting the database within specs was a bad thing to do? That's why I always stub the method on the model, then return a double if I need to check for `valid?` and such. That way I can expect the double to receive `valid?` and return true or false based on what I want to test (success or failure)

Comment: Thats kind of an exaggeration - stubbing out the database can be a good idea in unit tests to make your test suite faster.

But when you are testing something like a controller what you  really are doing is functional or integration testing and all that stubbing ruins the acuity of your tests.

Comment: DHH wrote [a pretty interesting blog post](http://david.heinemeierhansson.com/2014/tdd-is-dead-long-live-testing.html) on the subject a while back that managed to tickle a whole lot of people the wrong way.

Comment: @max I won't recommend anyone who wants to became a good developer to follow any of dhh's articles or his code

Comment: No rails for you then @RustamA.Gasanov.

Comment: I agree with not stubbing out models. But If I need to test a (service) object that is called by the controller, and depending of the input does a variety of things, it is so much easier to test that object separately and in the controller only test that it passes everything it needs to that object. Feature specs should than usually test that everything also integrated nicely in a basic scenario.

Comment: @trueunlessfalse thats a different scenario than your typical controller (and the original question) and more akin to when you're dealing with something like an API client that goes outside the application boundy. Yeah I would agree thats a place where stubbing could be useful.

Answer (score 13):

I handled this by creating in spec/rails_helper.rb

```
def strong_params(wimpy_params)
  ActionController::Parameters.new(wimpy_params).permit!
end
```

and then in a specific test, you can say:

```
expect(model).to receive(:update).with(strong_params foo: 'bar')
```

It's not much different from what you're already doing, but it makes the awkward necessity of that extra call a little more semantically meaningful.

Answer (score 2):

@max had good suggestions about how to avoid this altogether, and I agree they switched away from a hash to discourage using them with hashes interchangeably.

However, if you still want to use them, as a simple hack for more complex situations (for instance if you `expect` using a `a_hash_including`), you can try using something like this:

```
  .with( an_object_satisfying { |o| 
           o.slice(some_params) == ActionController::Parameters.new(some_params)
         })
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I implemented a hack around it in the specs while I decide on a better way. I basically added a `to_params` method which calls `ActionController::Parameters.new hash` so that it converts the hash in specs to `ActionController::Params` `expect(foo).to receive(:bar).with(to_params(foo: 'bar'))`

Comment: you monkey-patched a `to_params` method to `ActionController::Parameters` ?

Comment: In the example in the comment, `foo: 'bar'` is converted to an instance of `ActionController::Parameters`

Comment: Ahh ok. Yes, can easily do that. I used my above technique because I was using `a_hash_including` which won't allow for that kind of simple conversion. None of these are particularly ideal.